# How can I remove a previously appended source tag before appending a new one to an output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, append

```
$("#output").append("<img class='resp-output'
 src='"+foundImages[foundImages.length-1].url+"' /> ");"
```

That's what I have to append the class and source to "output", how to cut out the old source every time I call this, so that it only has one (the new) image source?

Comment: there is no `<source>` tag in this question. If you want to change the `<img>`tag's `src` property, then just call `$('#output>img')[0].src = yourNewValue;`

Answer (score 0):

assuming you only have an image inside the `$("#output")` element, you can clear it before every append as follows:

```
$("#output").html("");
```

it will just set its innerHtml to an empty string.

if you do have other elements inside the `$("#output")`, you can then save the image in a global variable before adding it:

```
var _currentIMG = $("<img class='resp-output' src='"+foundImages[foundImages.length-1].url+"' /> ");
$("#output").append(_currentIMG);
```

and then remove it before adding the new one:

```
_currentIMG.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem but not directly, I just added

```
$('#output').empty();
```

in an earlier function.

Thanks for your answer however, I'm sure I will use that method in the future.

Comment: `empty()` won't remove `("#output")`. It will just empty its contents, *which I suppose is what you are looking for* and it still remains in the DOM. `remove()` will completely remove it from the DOM.